# Position of Spring to support Vibrating feeder

Tags: mechanical-engineering

So I have to design a vibrating feeder of 55kg which moves the material (light objects eg. olives) on it in forward direction (linear motion). I am stucked on the positon of the spring. I mean which arrangement of spring will be better:
1. Spring can be placed at 4 corner of the vibrating feeder.
2. 2 in back corners and 2 in middle.

Is there any calculation or relation regarding this topic...?
I have attached the simple arrangment of what I have explained above.
[image: with 4 springs in corners]

[image: 2 springs in middle and 2 at the back]

Comment: In terms of calculations then spring stiffness, vibration frequency - avoiding the natural frequency, displacement ie how far it moves when vibrated, any effect of the load , like olives as they are loaded and spread... What are you considering?

Comment: The vibration frequency is suppose to be 60Hz, the displacement is 2mm. The load including the spreaded olives is 55kg. Avoiding natural frequency. I have problem regarding the position or placement of spring. what should be the distance between springs from inlet and outlet or its just fine if i place them into four corners.